# How to handle 60 secs timeout with heavy queries

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have to make some heavy queries in my datastore to obtain some high level information. When it reaches the 60 secs I get an error that I suppose its a timeout cut:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 207, in Handle
result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/admin/__init__.py", line 140, in xsrf_required_decorator
method(self)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/admin/__init__.py", line 348, in post
exec(compiled_code, globals())
File "<string>", line 28, in <module>
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2314, in next
return self.__model_class.from_entity(self.__iterator.next())
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1442, in from_entity
return cls(None, _from_entity=entity, **entity_values)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 958, in __init__
if isinstance(_from_entity, datastore.Entity) and _from_entity.is_saved():
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 814, in is_saved
self.__key.has_id_or_name())
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 565, in has_id_or_name
elems = self.__reference.path().element_list()
DeadlineExceededError
```

**This is not an application query, I am interacting with my app through the Interactive Console**, so this is not a live problem. My problem is that I have to iterate around all my application users, checking big amounts of data that I need to retrieve for each of them. I could do it one by one by hard coding their user_id, but it would be slow and non-efficient.

Can you guys think of any way I could do this faster? Is there anyway for selecting maybe 5 by five the users, like LIMIT=5 get only the first 5 users, but it would be great if I can get, first the 5 users, after that, the next 5 users and so on, iterating by all of them but with lighter queries. Can I set a longer timeout?

Any way you can think about I could deal with this problem?

Comment: related: [Dealing with DeadlineExceededErrors](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors)

Comment: Have you tried Remote API yet?

Comment: I have not tried Remote API, might it offer a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a cursor to pick up your search where you left off in conjunction with limit:

> Returns a base64-encoded cursor string denoting the position in the query's result set following the last result retrieved. The cursor string is safe to use in HTTP GET and POST parameters, and can also be stored in the Datastore or Memcache. A future invocation of the same query can provide this string via the start_cursor parameter or the with_cursor() method to resume retrieving results from this position.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_cursor

Comment: That might be what I am looking for, I should check that out

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a simple request handler to do the task.

Either write it in a way that it can be run on mapreduce, or launch a backend to run your handler.

Answer (score 0):

First, by getting your entities in batches will reduce the communication time of your application with the datastore significantly. For details on this, take a look at [10 things you (probably) didn't know about App Engine](http://googleappengine.blogspot.gr/2009/06/10-things-you-probably-didnt-know-about.html)

Then, you can assign this procedure to Task Queues that enable you to execute tasks up to 10 minutes. For more information on Task Queues, take a look at [The Task Queue Python API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/).

Finally, for tasks that need more time you can also consider the use of Backends. For more information you can take a look at [Backends (Python)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/).

Hope this helps.